# How do I get the randomly generated primary key of an inserted row in MariaDB/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

Okay, I am currently developing a website that is supposed to have a searchable database of pool pumps. As part of this system, to prevent people from reading hidden data, I had the primary key of the pool pump stock randomly generated. Here's the code I wrote for the MariaDB backend:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER random_pump_id BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_stock FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE temp_id MEDIUMINT;
    REPEAT
      SET temp_id = FLOOR(RAND() * 16777216);
    UNTIL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_stock WHERE pump_id = temp_id) <= 0 END REPEAT;
    SET NEW.pump_id = temp_id;
  END
$$
```

But now I've run into a dilemma. Every time I want to insert a row, I need a way to retrieve the primary key I just generated. I know if I used AUTO_INCREMENT I could use the LAST_INSERT_ID function, or lastInsertId in PDO. But since I am not using AUTO_INCREMENT, and instead am using a separate trigger, these functions will only return a 0. I know I can do it in PostgreSQL by using the RETURNING clause, but I can't find a way to accomplish this in MariaDB.

Does anyone know of any solution? Perhaps some obscure trigger I don't know about? Please?

Comment: "to prevent people from reading hidden data". If they have direct access to the database they can read the complete table anyway :-?

Comment: What you're doing is a terrible idea. Instead of your idea, what you should have done is use `auto_increment` but when you show the data to the user - encrypt the id's. That will prevent people from guessing what the actual value is. What you did there will annihilate your db performance, and that's not even the biggest issue.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález he means changing the URL or any other point of entry to another ID

Comment: @Mjh I don't understand what you mean by 'encrypt the id's'. The id's what? What exactly do the ids possess that I should encrypt. Unless you mean, 'encrypt the ids' but I don't know what you mean by that either. Unless you're referring to hashing, but that would only work for displaying the id. When I try to call a record using this 'encrypted id' it would be impossible unless you solved PvNP.

Comment: What I mean is encrypt the value of `auto_increment` when you show it to the end user in a URL or whatever kind of UI you have. When you receive the value back, decrypt it and use the database as it was meant to be used. Don't obfuscate or "randomize" the primary key, that's not a good idea. What you're after is disabling people from using sequential numbers to obtain data via a crawler or similar - your best approach is to encrypt this sensitive primary key information before you show it to the public. That's what I mean. Please don't randomize your primary keys, especially this way.

Comment: Yeah, you're not giving me a reason. You're saying it's a bad idea, without saying why. And if it's a problem with performance, I should point out encryption will also hurt performance, and will be happening for every element the visitors search for and view. Meanwhile I have one person who will be inserting items in the database on occasion.

Comment: InnoDB clusters based on primary key which is expected to be sequential (next one larger than previous). Using `last_insert_id()` won't work with your solution. You are prone to concurrency issues, how do you handle duplicates? To assert you're not getting a duplicate, you're performing a select - that won't prevent clashes at all, that will produce ERRORS because you will get false positives. Your numbers are still guessable since they're numbers. What you did there is introduce errors for no gain, and you made your writes slower. Encryption beats your solution by far.

Comment: You could have used `UUID()`, which is less-guessable than what you did (but still guessable). If you want to argue that encryption will be slower - no, it won't because encryption depends on CPU while your solution involves HDD subsystem into calculation - therefore, your solution will be I/O constrained while encryption will be CPU constrained. CPU speed >>>>>>> HDD speed, therefore encryption is by definition quicker method than yours, even though it's slower compared to no encryption. There's a few reasons, it's up to you if you'll listen. It's your project and good luck with that! :)

Comment: See, that's a reason. Thank you. I'm not a database expert by any stretch so I had no idea. The thing is, I also have no idea how to do what you suggest. Should I use AES or something? Is there a symmetrical encryption function in php? Because I couldn't find it, all I found were public key-based.

Comment: But it does strike me that a storage system that relies on sequential primary keys is really dumb since most of the time (at least, this is what I was taught) you don't want to use artificial primary keys, but instead something inherent to the subject. So Social Insurance Number, phone number, or email address. Are those ever sequential?

Comment: Storage engine wants to be fast, so it will happily create a hidden key if it can't use one from table definition (but that wastes space). However, since `auto_increment` does this job, they probably decided to use it so they don't waste too much space for no reason. Basically, using `auto_increment` should always be enough, using `unique` should be used for types of information you mentioned. PHP has libraries such as [this one](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), Laravel implements its own and gives you `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` functions.

Comment: Just a note - don't implement encryption on your own, use the library I linked, it has all the fine details handled for you, all you need to do is set up your symmetric key and use the library. `AES-128` should be more than fine for your purpose. As you see, this way you protect your data from prying eyes and you don't prevent yourself from using database-specific functions (`last_insert_id()` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

- Presumably you have some other way to locate the record?  Probably via a `UNIQUE` key?  If so, the fetch the row after adding the random id.
- Don't use a trigger, instead write application code.  (Triggers can't solve all problems.)

Comment: No, there's no reliable way to call the record using a UNIQUE field. Also, I like a trigger. It runs automatically on the server without me having to bother. PHP code is inherently less efficient. But none of it matters, I solved the problem by using AUTO_INCREMENT and encrypting the primary keys. Works much better for my purposes.